# Exception occurred starting up Jetty while using URLRewrite

Tags: java, url-rewriting, jetty

I configured `URLRewrite` to my application. But when I tried to start up my Jetty server with Java code, an exception occurred as below:

```
    2016-11-22 14:23:34.756:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/Users/xxx/Documents/Developer/myapp/src/main/webapp/}
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1210)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
```

But it worked when I deployed it to `Tomcat` server.

Anyone can help with this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that it's caused by the version of `servlet-api`, which is embedded in `Jetty` but not the one supports. So I upgraded `Jetty` to a newer one and changed the version of `web.xml` to 3.0. Then it works.

Hope this helps!